# $attribute->isInSet($setId) returning true even when $attribute isn't in the attribute set

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeSets = Mage::helper('my_helper')->GetAllAttributeSets();

foreach($attributeSets as $attributeSet)
{
    if($attribute->isInSet($attributeSet->getAttributeSetId()))
    {
        $attributeSetId = $attributeSet->getAttributeSet();
        break;
    }
}
```

While debugging, I expect the first iteration of the loop to skip over the if.  It keeps returning true.

Digging deeper, I see the isInSet() function has this:

```
public function isInSet($setId)
{
    if (!$this->hasAttributeSetInfo()) {
        return true;
    }
```

This is where I get my true from, which makes no sense to me.  hasAttributeSetInfo() is just a magic method which checks to see if attribute_set_info isset...which it is not.  So the if condition resolves to true, and true is returned, effectively not returning the expected value.

**Is this a bug?**

**Or am i just using it incorrectly?**

Edit:
The entire point of what I'm trying to do is get all admin user defined attribute sets that do not have $attribute in them.  In my specific case, there will only be two admin user defined attribute sets.  One of these sets has $attribute in it.

**The solution I went with was to create a system config field which uses a custom source model.  The source model converts all the admin user defined attribute sets to an option array, which can be explicitly targeted, thereby removing the need for my original question.**

I still feel like there's a better answer out there for my original question though.  I find it difficult to believe that I can't easily figure out to which attribute sets an attribute belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing.  Very inefficient and I feel bad.

```
foreach($attributeSets as $attributeSet)
{
    $attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSet->getAttributeSetId());

    foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if($profileAttribute->getAttributeId() === $attribute['attribute_id'])
        {
            $attributeSetId = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetId();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```